# Str.contains and isin function do not return all correct rows of dataframe

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, dataframe

Given a list of strings L1 `L1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']`, I need to extract the rows which contain the values given in list L1. I used the isin function: `df[df['column1'].isin(L1)]`

The data contains the following values in a column 1:

1. 'a'
2. 'c'
3. 'a, d'
4. 'brp'

The data contains the following values in a column 2:

1. ['a']
2. ['c']
3. ['a', 'd']
4. ['brp']

The output I need should print all the rows because the string 'a' is present in L1, but, the output returns only 3 rows: rows 1, 2 (that is the rows containing strings 'a', 'c')

How do I modify the code so that it returns the 3rd row as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method for this using a regex pattern:

```
import pandas as pd

L1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1": ["a", "c", "a, d", "brp"]
})

# use the '|' character to check if the strings contains any of the characters in L1
df[df["column1"].str.contains("|".join(L1))]
```